# Service not executing every 15 seconds

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a service that needs to run every 15 seconds. Interval is setup in the config file. When i start/restart the service, worker thread only executes once and performs its intended action.

config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <!-- Worker thread will start after 15 seconds interval -->
    <add key="Interval" value="15000"/>

  </appSettings>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>

</configuration>
```

Service Code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

using WorkflowSupport;
using BitFactory.Logging;
using Efts.Framework.Resources;
using Efts.Framework.Core;


namespace Efts.Framework.Service
{
    public partial class QueueService : ServiceBase
    {
        private WorkflowManager _worker;

        public QueueService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // get the polling interval or initialize if missing
                var pollTime = int.Parse(ConfigHelper.Interval());

                // create the thread worker
                _worker = new WorkflowManager("Queue Service",
                                                     new Worker(), //in Efts.Framework.Core
                                                     pollTime,
                                                     true);
                // wire up the event listeners
                WireupWorkflowManagerEvents(_worker);

                // go
                _worker.Start();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ConfigLogger.Instance.LogError(String.Format("{0}{1}::{2}", ex.Message,
                                                             String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ex.InnerException.Message)
                                                                 ? String.Empty
                                                                 : String.Format("::{0}", ex.InnerException.Message)
                                                             , ex.StackTrace));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _worker.Stop();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wireups the workflow manager events.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="workflowManager">The request workflow manager.</param>
        private static void WireupWorkflowManagerEvents(WorkflowManager workflowManager)
        {
            workflowManager.Started +=
                ((sender, e) => ConfigLogger.Instance.LogDebug(String.Format("{0}: Workflow started", workflowManager.Name)));

            workflowManager.Stopped +=
                ((sender, e) => ConfigLogger.Instance.LogDebug(String.Format("{0}: Workflow stopped", workflowManager.Name)));

            workflowManager.BeginWork +=
                ((sender, e) => ConfigLogger.Instance.LogDebug(String.Format("{0}: Workflow worker is beginning work", workflowManager.Name)));

            workflowManager.EndWork +=
                ((sender, e) => ConfigLogger.Instance.LogDebug(String.Format("{0}: Workflow worker is done.", workflowManager.Name)));

            workflowManager.Message += ((sender, e) => ConfigLogger.Instance.LogInfo(String.Format("{0}: {1}", workflowManager.Name, e.Message)));
        }

    }
}
```

I am little bit at loss here. What am i missing here?

Comment: Does the service stop after the worker has executed once? Are you sure that the worker will re-execute itself after the first pass? Please post that code if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. In this instance it was problem at my end. I was specifing interval in milliseconds where as it it should have been in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've never used WorkFlows, but I've written a lot of Windows Services. Normally the way I structure something like this is:

1. Make the timer global to the main thread (the one with OnStart, OnStop, etc.).
2. Write the processing code that will run in the worker thread as fire and forget.
3. In the OnStart, set the timer's interval property, wire up the OnElapsed event handler and last thing in the OnStart - start the timer.
4. In the OnElapsed event handler - this is important - first thing stop the timer. Fire off the worker thread to do its thing. Last thing in this event handler, restart the timer.

First thing I would do is evaluate if this process really needs (benefits) from the multi threading. If not it is a layer of complexity that you should avoid, if so then so be it - just be careful.